# List the days between two given dates

Tags: sql, teradata

I am working on a code like this

```
CREATE FUNCTION edw_devdb.test ( StartDate Date, EndDate Date)
     RETURNS DATE
     LANGUAGE SQL
     DETERMINISTIC
     CONTAINS SQL
     SPECIFIC test.myudf
     CALLED ON NULL INPUT
     SQL SECURITY DEFINER
     COLLATION INVOKER
     INLINE TYPE 1
     RETURN 
SYS_CALENDAR.Calendar.calendar_date between StartDate and EndDate;
```

I need a function that returns the list of dates between two given dates in teradata. Can someone help me on this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this in a SQL UDF in Teradata.

Why do you need this list in a function? If StartDate and EndDate are columns in a table Teradata's EXPAND ON might be used:

```
SELECT BEGIN(pd)
FROM SYS_CALENDAR.CALENDAR  -- your table here
WHERE calendar_date = DATE
EXPAND ON PERIOD(StartDate, EndDate + 1) AS p
```

Of course you'll use your own table instead of SYS_CALENDAR.CALENDAR, this is just to get a single row.

Comment: where is the documentation for this?

Answer (score -1):

Use this logic inside your function

```
; WITH  CTE as
 (
     SELECT CAST('01/jan/2014' AS DATE) as DATES //Use Fromdate as parameter instead of '01/jan/2014'
     UNION ALL
     SELECT DATEADD(DAY,1,DATES )
     FROM    CTE
     WHERE   DATES < cast('10/jan/2014' AS DATE) //Use Todate as parameter instead of '01/jan/2014'
 )
 SELECT DISTINCT DATES 
 FROM    CTE
```